# How do I call an upside down jQuery.slideDown()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

In the web app I'm working on I want to do a little slide up notification, like on twitter or your desktop.  jQuery's `.slideDown` does exactly what I want, but it's upside down.  The `.slideUp` doesn't execute an upside down version of slideDown. Instead it hides stuff, like after your cleaning up an old message you've displayed with `slideDown`.

So what's the simplest code to do an upside down `slideDown()` in jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've put `jquery-ui` into tags, here's jqueryUI solution (need to have `Effects Core`)

```
 $('#box').show('slide', {direction: 'down'});
```

Updated patrick's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aVNL6/2/

Comment: +1 for great answer!  I looked forever for the documentation on the 'direction' option parameter.  Do you have any links to the official documentation for the possible options?

Comment: Yeah, it's here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects, slide options are here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide#options

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I had trouble finding it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're saying that you want the reveal (slideDown) to reveal the content from bottom to top, you'll need to have your CSS give a fixed `bottom` position to the element.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aVNL6/

*html*

```
<a href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='box'></div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    background: yellow;
}
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

*js*

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#box').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Information about many possible ways to slide things using jQuery can be found on [learningjquery.com](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

Comment: apparently this is not the page I thought about. The other one came up with resolutions for even more sliding effects and directions. But I can't find it in my bookmarks anymore... :-(